# Simplify as a fraction in lowest terms

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving, fractions

[image]

How would you simplify the above without directly calculating each part of the expression?

Taken from the 2009 IWYMIC

Comment: It would be nice to share your answer if you get one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Mark's cryptic hint isn't sufficient for you, here is another one:-

$$x^4 + x^2 + 1 = x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - x^2 = (x^2+1)^2-x^2 = (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1). $$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a cryptic hint which will help if you see a main idea - so it still gives you a chance to puzzle something substantial out yourself.$$x^2+x+1=(x+1)^2-(x+1)+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint
$$
x^3 -1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1).
$$
That should help you with expressions like $5^4 + 5^2 + 1$.

Comment: While correct, I am not sure this is enough.  The $\frac 1{3^4+3^2+1}$ term becomes $\frac {3^2-1}{3^6-1}$ but how to get from that to $\frac 1{7\cdot 13}$ is not clear to me

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, there's more work to be done that I haven't followed through. Factoring those differences of squares is a natural next step. Maybe I should have posted this only as a comment labeled "possible hint".

Comment: Maybe the suggestion to consider similarly $x^3+1$ would be a nudge too much?